# What is the Difference between Partially Commited and Commited State in Transaction?

Tags: transactions, rdbms

I know that if a transaction executes all its operations successfully, it is said to be committed. All of its effects are now permanently established on the database system.

But I don't understand *What is the Partially Committed state?*

According to definition:

> Partially Committed state is When a transaction executes its final operation, it is said to be in a partially committed state.

As both Partially Committed and Committed states occur after all transaction operations has been executed.

How to differentiate between these two states of transactions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From [this reference](http://ecomputernotes.com/database-system/rdbms/transaction), a partially committed state appears to occur when all components of a database transaction have finished, and the RDBMS has logically committed to persisting those changes to the database, but has not yet actually persisted them.  I use the word "logically" here because it is possible that after the work of a transaction has finished a failure could still occur.  To take this possibility into account, the RDBMS writes out enough information to disk to guarantee that, even if a failure were to occur, the result from the transaction could be recreated and the database could be updated appropriately.

So from a logical point of view, a partially committed state and a committed state are identical.  But they differ in that in the former the database itself may not actually reflect the results of the transaction.

Here is a helpful diagram showing the various states of a database transaction, taken from the above reference:

[image]

Comment: I clearly cited the reference whence I obtained the diagram, and this answer does not deserve to be downvoted.